# TypeError: message.replay is not a function

Tags: node.js, json

```
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');


const client = new Client(
    { intents: [
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS
    ] 
    });


client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('bot say kys!');
});

client.on('messageCreate',message => 
{
/* the error i think is here but im not realy sure the error said (TypeError: message.replay 
   enter code here`is not a function ) */
    if(message.content === 'hi')
{
    message.replay('hello')
}
});




client.login(token);
```

im gonna rewrite he next sentence because the website said
for information i'm trying to make a discord bot and this is my first time

Answer (score 0):

This is not `replay` but `reply`

```
message.reply("content");
```